# How do I bind a function to elements inside of a Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-events

I'm working with Web Components and try to bind a `click` event to an element inside of the Shadow DOM.

**1. component.html included as `<link rel="import" ...>` inside of index.html**

```
<template id="my-element">
    <section>
        <header>
            <content select="h1"></content>
            <button></button>
        </header>
        <content select="div"></content>
    </section>
</template>
```

**2. later element usage:**

```
<my-element>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <div>...</div>
</my-element>
```

**3. Access element and bind a function to it**

Now I want to *add* an `addEventListener()` to the `<button>` inside of my `<my-element>` *(which is unfortunately hidden through the `#shadow-root`)*. Like:

```
var elemBtn = document.querySelector('my-element button');
elemBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // do stuff
});
```

But that won't work. **How do I achieve that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this without involving the window object. Here's a full example:

```
<!-- Define element template -->
<template>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <button id="btn">Click me</button>
</template>

<!-- Create custom element definition -->
<script>
  var tmpl = document.querySelector('template');

  var WidgetProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

  WidgetProto.createdCallback = function() {
    var root = this.createShadowRoot();
    root.appendChild(document.importNode(tmpl.content, true));
    // Grab a reference to the button in the shadow root
    var btn = root.querySelector('#btn');
    // Handle the button's click event
    btn.addEventListener('click', this.fireBtn.bind(this));
  };

  // Dispatch a custom event when the button is clicked
  WidgetProto.fireBtn = function() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('btn-clicked'));
  };

  var Widget = document.registerElement('my-widget', {
    prototype: WidgetProto
  });
</script>

<!-- Use the element -->
<my-widget></my-widget>

<!-- Listen for its click event -->
<script>
  var widget = document.querySelector('my-widget');
  widget.addEventListener('btn-clicked', function() {
    alert('the button was clicked');
  });
</script>
```

[Example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mefaje/2/edit)

Comment: Well that's frustrating. Your solution is way smarter than mine :D

Comment: @morkro Would you mind to mark this answer as correct?

Comment: Sure! Thanks @robdodson for showing me a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that creating a custom `createEvent('MouseEvent');` inside of `<template>` will do the trick!

**TL;DR** http://jsfiddle.net/morkro/z0vbh11v/

---

**1. First, you need to add the `onclick=""`-attribute to our `<template>` and create a custom event:**

```
<template id="my-element">
    <section>
        <header>
            <content select="h1"></content>
            <button onclick="callEventOnBtn()"></button>
        </header>
        <content select="div"></content>
    </section>

    <script>
        var btnEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
        btnEvent.initEvent('oncomponentbtn', true, true);
        var callEventOnBtn = function() {
            window.dispatchEvent(btnEvent);
        };
    </script>
</template>
```

I create the custom event inside of the `<template>` and automatically dispatch it to the global `window` object when the Custom Element gets used later.

**2. Now we can listen to that event, when clicking the `<button>` on our custom element**

```
window.addEventListener('oncomponentbtn', function(event) {
    // do stuff
});
```